# JavaFX: TextFields displayed from array, array updated / increased on button click - how to force the scene to redraw the updated array

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

I have a program that displays animals and their names:

```
    private int TOTAL_ANIMALS = 5;

    private TextField[] animals;
    private TextField[] names
```

```
public AnimalsApp  {
  animals = new TextField[TOTAL_ANIMALS];
  names = new TextFields[TOTAL_ANIMALS];
  for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_ANIMALS; i++)  {
    animals[i] = new TextField();
    names[i] = new TextField();
  }
}
```

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
       GridPane grid = new GridPane();
       ...
       for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_ANIMALS; i++)  {
         grid.add(animals[i], 0, i);
         grid.add(names[i], 1, i);
       }
```

The method associated with `Add animal` button:

```
public void addAnimals()  {
  animals = Arrays.copyOf(animals, TOTAL_ANIMALS + 1);
  names = Arrays.copyOf(names, TOTAL_ANIMALS + 1);

  animals[TOTAL_ANIMALS] = new TextField();
  names[TOTAL_ANIMALS] = new TextField();
  TOTAL_ANIMALS++;

  System.out.println("Animals updated");
}
```

The code inside `addAnimals` does execute, but the new text field doesn't appear. How should I fix it?

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Use `List`s instead of arrays, so that you're not replicating existing libraries. If you want to make the grid pane automatically update when you add to the lists, use `ObservableList`s and register listeners with them that update the grid pane. Creating an `Animal` model class would probably make the code cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the text fields to grid, just creating a textfield doesn't show it you need to add it to your like you did in your start function. You would also need to make the GridPane a variable in the class.

```
public void addAnimals()  {
  animals = Arrays.copyOf(animals, TOTAL_ANIMALS + 1);
  names = Arrays.copyOf(names, TOTAL_ANIMALS + 1);

  animals[TOTAL_ANIMALS] = new TextField();
  names[TOTAL_ANIMALS] = new TextField();
  grid.add(animals[TOTAL_ANIMALS], 0, TOTAL_ANIMALS);
  grid.add(names[TOTAL_ANIMALS], 1, TOTAL_ANIMALS);
  TOTAL_ANIMALS++;

  System.out.println("Animals updated");
}
```

Comment: I was hoping the code that's already in the `start` method for displaying all the data from the array properly (with correct positions etc) could be reused somehow? Maybe there is a way to get the start() method execute again?

Comment: You could add a method that added a textfields to the grid, and execute that in the start function.

Comment: I also have `grid.add(btAddAnimal 0, TOTAL_ANIMALS + 1);` inside the `start`. If I just `grid.add()` from outside the `start` the new animals would overflow the button

Comment: You could move the buttons, with `grid.remove(button); grid.add(button, ...)` .

Comment: I don't want to do virtually the same work `start()` does again. Is there a method to force refresh the scene so that start was called again on the updated arrays?

Comment: You could call `this.start(stage);`

Comment: You might wanna look into the javafx [ListView](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html) then